# EventEmitter subscribe are not executing on Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm developing a DialogComponent and i have some problems on my unit test, my event emitter of close dialog are not executing on unit test, i have been mocked this return but still not working.

Here is my DialogService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DialogService {
  private injector = inject(EnvironmentInjector)
  private appRef = inject(ApplicationRef)
  private compRef: ComponentRef<DialogComponent>
 
  open(options: Options): DialogComponent {
    this.compRef = createComponent<DialogComponent>(DialogComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
    })
 
    this.compRef.instance.options = options;
    this.compRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
 
    document.body.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
 
    this.appRef.attachView(this.compRef.hostView);
 
    return this.compRef.instance;
  }
}
```

My DialogComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pmc-dialog',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, IconComponent, ButtonComponent],
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DialogComponent {
  @Output() onClose = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onConfirm = new EventEmitter();
  options: Options;
 
  private dialogService: DialogService = inject(DialogService);
 
  confirm() {
    this.onConfirm.emit();
  }
 
  close() {
    this.onClose.emit()
  }
}
```

My function who called the Dialog:

```
unlockProposal(proposal: Proposal) {
    const modal: DialogComponent = this.dialogService.open({
      data: {
        title: `Análise bloqueada por ${proposal.blockedBy}`,
        message: 'Gostaria de seguir com o desbloqueio da análise dessa proposta?',
        icon: 'warning-circle'
      },
      config: {
        width: '600',
      }
    })
 
 
    modal.onConfirm.subscribe({ <-- *HERE IS MY PROBLEM, IN MY TEST, THIS BLOCK ARE NEVER EXECUTED*
      next: () => { 
        this.cardDeskService.unlockProposal(proposal.id).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            modal.loading.set(false);
 
            this.dialogService.close();
 
            this.updateList();
          },
          error: () => {
            this.toastrService.error('Erro ao desbloquear a proposta', `Não foi possível desbloquear a proposta ${proposal.code}`)
 
            modal.loading.set(false);
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

And my test suit:

```
  fit('should unlock proposal correctly', async () => {
    const { component } = await render();
 
 
    const spyGetProposals = spyOn(component.dialogService, 'open').and.returnValue({
      onConfirm: of()
    } as any)
    const spyUnlock = spyOn(component.cardDeskService, 'unlockProposal')
 
    component.unlockProposal({ id: 5, blockedBy: 'XPTO', code: 'CC-XXXX12-PF'} as Proposal)
 
    expect(spyGetProposals).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      data: {
        title: `Análise bloqueada por XPTO`,
        message: 'Gostaria de seguir com o desbloqueio da análise dessa proposta?',
        icon: 'warning-circle'
      },
      config: {
        width: '600',
      }
    })

    expect(spyUnlock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(5)
  })
```

The result of the test is:
`Expected spy unlockProposal to have been called with [ 5 ] but it was never called.

Comment: put at least something in `of()` so there is an event `onConfirm: of(null)`